# Will strcmp compare utf-8 strings in code point order?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, glib

In a C program, I want to sort a list of valid UTF-8-encoded strings in Unicode code point order. No collation, no locale-awareness.

So I need a compare function.  It's easy enough to write such a function that iterates over the unicode characters. (I happen to be using [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.36/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-next-char), so I'd iterate with`g_utf8_next_char` and compare the return values of `g_utf8_next_char`.)

But what I'm wondering, out of curiousity and possibly simplicity and efficiency, is: will a simple byte-for-byte `strcmp` (or `g_strcmp`) actually do the same job? I'm thinking that it should, since UTF-8 [encodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) the most significant bits first, and a code point that needs encoding in N+1 bytes will have a larger initial byte than a code point that needs to be encoded in N bytes.

But maybe I'm missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, UTF-8 preserves codepoint order, so you can just use `strcmp`. That's one of the (many) beautiful points of UTF-8.

One caveat is that *codepoints* in Unicode are UTF-32 values, and some people who talk about collating Unicode strings in "codepoint" order are actually using the word "codepoint" incorrectly to mean "UTF-16 code unit". If you want the order to match UTF-16 code unit collation, a good bit more work is involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was about to follow up on my use case and how I don't think the caveat applies, and then saw that this information is right there in [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n#DocumentOrder) I'm trying to implement: "Lexicographic comparison, which orders strings from least to greatest alphabetically, is based on the UCS codepoint values, which is equivalent to lexicographic ordering based on UTF-8." `:-)`